# Our dependency track tool using the NVD database displays that quarkus 3.2.5 still has CVE-2023-1584

Tags: security, quarkus, cve

Is the https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2023-1584 fixed in quarkus 3.2.5 and following 3.3.x releases?

Comment: Yes but I'll need to send an update to NVD to have it marked as fixed upstream as well, thanks. FYI it is only a risk if `HTTP` is used which is fundamentally insecure to use with OIDC.

Comment: FYI, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/32192, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/33414